# Hibernate Cascade PERSIST

Tags: hibernate, jpa, cascade, persist

I have a general question about Hibernate that I'm batteling with.

I have class A and class B, where B is dependent on A

In my code when I call em.persist(objOfTypeA) I would expect the insert to go and insert into both tables AAA and BBB. If I manually presist A get A's ID and fill it in the list for each object and then persist that list, things are working.
But I would expect this to happen *magically* by Hibernate.

Am I doing something wrong?
Or am I just expecting too much of Hibernate?

Thanks

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AAA")
@Veto
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Long id;


    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private Long name;

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="a", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private List<B> b;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "BBB")
@Veto
public class B {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="Id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="AId")
    private Long aId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private Long name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "AId", referencedColumnName="Id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private A a;
...     
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally worked it out.
None of the examples I was given or found told me exactly what was wrong, it was only after my own experimentation that I managed to come to this conclusion:

Instead of having

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="a", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
private List<B> b;
```

that didn't work (FK was still coming as NULL)

This did work:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
@JoinColumn(name="AId")
@NotNull
private List<B> b;
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. The problem is that Hibernate wants the A to be set on the B before persisting. This worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795649/jpa-persisting-a-one-to-many-relationship

Answer (score 1):

Modify the mapping of class `B` as below,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BBB")
@Veto
public class B {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="Id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="AId", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Long aId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private Long name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "AId", referencedColumnName="Id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private A a;
...     
}
```

You were using the attributes `updatable = false, insertable = false` at wrong place and I have corrected it.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9442483/507864) to understand how they works.

Comment: Hi ManuPK,
 
Thanks for your answer, but this didn't solve my problem.
 
While trying to persist (A) I am getting an error that aId for B is null.

ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=aId, rootBeanClass=class com.test.model.B, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}

I am not sure if on the SQL Server side I have to have both id's (A's and B's) as identity or will Hibernate take care of that? But I am assuming that's ok as it's not complaining for that it's complaining on the FK.

Comment: DB is looking like this:
Table1: AAA
Id bigint not null,
Name varchar(100)

Table2: BBB
Id bigint not null,
AId bigint not null,
Name varchar(100)

Thanks!

Comment: I went back to the DB and removed 'not null' from AId and also the 
@NotNull from aId in B class. Now the persist is successful But when I look at the DB. AAA is all good, but BBB is missing the AId.
Help..

Comment: Follow this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/) to create the classes.