# How to cascade @ManyToOne bidirectional relations with cascading?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to automatically persist/merge `Address` entities of persons. Once created, they should be updateable by any person, but not removed if a `Person` is removed.

```
//each person can only have one address
@Entity
public class Person {
    @ManyToOne
    private Address address;
}


//one address can be assigned to multiple persons (eg family members)
@Entity
public class Address {
    @OneToMany
    private List<Person> persons;
}
```

Questions:

1. How would I have to write the `cascade` annotations for this requirement?
2. How would I create those entities? `person.setAddress(address)` or `address.getPersons().add(person)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `@Cascade({CascadeType.MERGE})` on both would be what you are looking for.

I would probably create and persist a `Person` without an address, and then in the `Address` entity have something like:

```
public void addPerson(Person person) {
   persons.add(person);
   person.setAdderess(this);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. To answer your first question, for your desired requirement you
   should use  `cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE` to avoid removing an
   `Address` if a `Person` is removed:

> ```
> @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE mappedBy = "person")
> ```

You may take a look at [this article](http://nverma-tech-blog.blogspot.com/2013/03/jpa-20-hibernate-orphanremoval.html) it explains the same behavior in the same situation, saying that:

> *If only cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE is specified no automatic action is taken since removing a relationship is not a remove operation.*

2. For the second question to persist both entities you should use the
   two statements together, like this:

> ```
> person.setAddress(address);
> address.getPersons().add(person);
> ```

Take a look [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1796501/3669624) for further information.

Comment: Are you sure about adding the `CascadeType.REMOVE`. Shouldn't this be the only cascade type the should be *left* out, so that the remove is *not* cascaded?

Comment: As it says in the article: *If only cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE is specified no automatic action is taken since removing a relationship is not a remove operation.*

Comment: Don't take it out of the context. The sentense refers to the statement before with `orphanRemoval=true`: *If orphanRemoval=true is specified the removed address instance is automatically removed. If only cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE is specified no automatic action is taken since removing a relationship is not a remove operation.*

Comment: And what does that mean? They are separtaed sentences!