# Save object with OneToMany from JSON to database

Tags: java, json, hibernate, rest, jax-rs

I'm trying to send the following JSON to a REST API and persist on database, but only the `Product` is created, the `Image` it is not.

> {"name":"pen", 
>   "description":"red pen", 
>   "images":[{"type":"jpeg"}] 
>   }

@Controller

```java
@POST
@Path("/product/add")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response addProduct(Product product) {
    service.createProduct(product);
}
```

@Service

```java
@Autowired
private ProductDAO productDAO;

@Autowired
private ImageDAO imageDAO;

public void createProduct(Product product) {
    productDAO.save(product);
}
```

@Product

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class Product implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer productId;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
private String description;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="product")
private Set<Image> images;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="parent")
private Set<Product> children;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_PRODUCT_ID")
private Product parent;
```

@Image

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Image implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer imageId;

@Column(name = "TYPE")
private String type;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", nullable = false)
private Product product;
```

At the `@POST` method, when print the `Product` object received, this is what returns:

> Product [productId=null, name=pen, description=red pen, images=[Image [id=null, type=jpeg, product=null]], children=null, parent=null]

The correct way is to first persist the `Product`, and then persist the `Image` or the Hibernate can automatically persist the `Image` when I persist the `Product`?

Answer (score 0):

`Hibernate` takes care of persisting your child entities if your bidirectional mapping is correctly implemented and you have set proper relationships between your entity objects.

You have a `Product` entity that has a collection of `Image`. `Product` entity is the parent entity here. You can simply set proper relations between `Product` and `Image` entities and persist only `Product`. Hibernate will persist your parent as well as your child entities.

> What you need to do

```
Product product = new Product();
product.setName("PRODUCT_NAME");

Set<Image> productImages = new HashSet<>();

Image productProfileImage = new Image();
productProfileImage.setType("PROFILE");
productProfileImage.setProduct(product);
//..set other fields
productImages.add(productProfileImage);

Image productCoverImage = new Image();
productCoverImage.setType("COVER");
productCoverImage.setProduct(product);
//..set other fields
productImages.add(productCoverImage);

product.setImages(productImages);
productRepository.save(product);  //Persist only your product entity and the  mapped child entities will be persisted
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795649/jpa-persisting-a-one-to-many-relationship) similar answer.

**PS: I have not tested the code but this should work.**

Comment: I would suggest to test your code before submitting it here. It can always be the case, that you missed something and others may be confused about it. For that reason, I downvoted the answer.

Comment: @alexander Brother this is a platform to help others and not post throughly tested pieces of code. There might be situations where through testing is not possible or very cumbersome.

Comment: And this is not a platform to be called brother. I will not withdraw my opinion, I saw so many answers which are not tested and which does not work.

Comment: @alexander Ok Sir