# Spring JPA oneToMany relationships causing null foreign key exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have a User object with a list of CardInformation objects (their payment options). If I create a new user and new CardInformation at the same time - the foreign key referencing the User database id is null (which makes sense as I haven't persisted the object). I was under the impression spring or hibernate handles this for you when saving the User object. If not - how is this solved? By setting the User model reference in the CardInformation object?

I have kept the models simple and removed most the data to easily see the onetomany relationship details.

CardInformation in database has foreign key owner_id - referencing user_id column.

These are my models - User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class UserPersistenceModel {

/** Table id reference. */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long id;

/** First name. */
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

/** Email. */
@Column(name = "email", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String email;

/** List of users payment options. */
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userPersistenceModel", cascade = 
CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<CardInformationPersistenceModel> cardInformationPersistenceModels;
```

Plus all getters/setters.

CardInformation model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CardInformation")
public class CardInformationPersistenceModel {

/** Unique db id. */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "card_id")
private Long id;

/** Card Holder Full Name. */
@Column(name = "CardHolderName")
private String cardHolderName;

/**
 * Many-1 reference to owner model.
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", nullable = false)
private UserPersistenceModel userPersistenceModel;
```

Plus all getters/setters etc.

**The error I receive is - owner_id is null when saving user object**

Comment: Have you checked this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795649/jpa-persisting-a-one-to-many-relationship

Comment: Not sure how I didn't see that - but yeah that does answer my question - thanks Akashdeep

Comment: Could you show how you save the `User` object?