# OneToOne and OneToMany not storing Parent Id (IdClass)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am currently working on a project with following data structure:

```java
public class PinaColadaId implements Serializable {
    private UUID id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date time;
    // Constructor + Getters and Setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "pina_coladas")
@IdClass(PinaColadaId.class)
public class PinaColadaEntity {

    @Column(columnDefinition = "char(255)")
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")
    private @Id UUID id;

    private @Id @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) Date time;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "entityID", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private PineappleWrapper pineapple;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityID", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<CoconutWrapper> coconuts;

    // Constructor + Getters and Setters
}

@Entity
public class PineappleWrapper {
    private @Id @GeneratedValue long id;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String origin;

    @OneToOne
    private PinaColadaEntity entityID;

    // Constructor + Getters and Setters
}

@Entity
public class CoconutWrapper {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue long id;
    private int shipmentNumber;
    private int juice;

    @ManyToOne
    private PinaColadaEntity entityID;

    // Constructor + Getters and Setters
}
```

The issue is that Spring Boot together with Hibernate and JPA correctly generate all the tables in my database, however when I attempt to store PineappleWrapper or CoconutWrapper, it stores all the values of PineappleWrapper and/or CoconutWrapper except for the id and time of the parent. The columns are generated yet they store the value "null".

Any and all help is much appreciated, -AwesomeDude091

Edit: I am aware of the JoinColumn annotation and it proposed implementation in my Wrapper classes, but I do not know how to use them with my two ID variables (id and time)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA - Persisting a One to Many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795649/jpa-persisting-a-one-to-many-relationship)

Comment: @lane.maxwell I found such explanations, but I do not know how to apply these to my id AND my time id variables

Comment: Share your logic where you are constructing and persisting the Entities as well as your `PinaColadaId` class.

Comment: I shared the ID class its the first one

Comment: You have to map the foreign keys using the @JoinColumns annotation wrapping two JoinColumn definitions